# Use of maven with artifactory and jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

I am very new to maven, artifactory and jenkins as well. I made a directory 'repository' under path /home/apache-maven-3.2.1/.m2/repository. I am trying to deploy a jar through artifactory UI into this directory. Please suggest some configuration so that i can do this. Jars which i deployed already were deployed successfully but when I see inside repository, there is nothing in it.

One other question is how to set dependencies while deploying any artifacts?

These questions may be silly because i don't know anything about the above three tools and i am unable to set relation between them also.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Artifactory has its own storage for deployed artifacts, you usually do not deploy to "a directory". If you want to use your local Maven repository, you install the artifact. Please read the docs and clarify your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to archive some java files, properties files and XML files. Actually my confusion is that only, if artifactory has its own storage then why one needs to use it with maven?

Comment: Artifactory is (mainly) used to store jar, war and ear files so that other builds (with Maven or Gradle) can access them. If you want to store *.java, *.properties and *.xml files, you use a version management system like svn or git.

Comment: Thank you sir! This line will help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also quite new to maven and still struggling with it, but the thing to do is try to configure a pom.xml file with your settings. Since you didn't give any indication on how the jar file has to be build, you got to find a guide in order to do it.
Useful links:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_pom.htm

Hope this can help!

Comment: Thank you! But my problem has not been solved still yet. Actually i am unable to figure out the real use of maven as i commented above. Because of that i am unable to configure things properly.

Comment: Maven let's you make a jar or war or another compressed file that can be used by other programs, webapps or applications. You need maven in order to compact all dependencies and libraries in an automate way. It could be a bit difficult to set things up.. I suggest you to check some examples and then start your own pom file!

Comment: Is it necessary to create and use pom.xml. Actually i read somewhere that pom.xml OR settings.xml. That is why i am using settings.xml only.